# Problems with pound sterling symbol in php mysql replacement

Tags: php, mysql

I am replacing characters in my mysql database and while I can replace chacters such as $ or ~ for some I can't get it to replace the following symbol £. Why?

```
$sql[$handle]['sql'] = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.$field.' = REPLACE('.$field.',\''£'\',\''.$replace.'\')';
```

Comment: Is there an error? Or doesn't it do anything at all? Have you tried pasting your generated SQL directly into the database?

Comment: You have extra quotes in there don't you? `',\''£'\',\''` => `',\'£\',\''` maybe?

Comment: No error, it just doesn't do anything - well it replaces all the other characters except for that one (£)

Comment: Hmm no, hope I dont? Because it works fine with the other characters.

Comment: What character set is being used for that field?

Comment: Agree with Mahn that while may not be your issue what you pasted is not correct syntax.  `syntax error, unexpected '£' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in`...

Comment: @user1658413 `echo ',\''£'\',\'';` definitively gives a parse error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing the `'£'` with `CHR(156)` in your replace syntax